# push notification on mobile android

Tags: push-notification, android-notifications

I have issue with push notification on mobile android,
I have the following code , I need the solution for when I  get notification on mobile when my app is active I want notification like popup it means until unless user takes action it should go away.

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { ExpirationPlugin } from "workbox-expiration";
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from "workbox-strategies";
import { fetchDataById } from "./redux/features/appointment/dataSlice";
import { AsyncThunkAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Dispatch, AnyAction } from "redux";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./redux/app/hook";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp("/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$");
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== "navigate") {
      return false;
    }

    // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.
    if (url.pathname.startsWith("/_")) {
      return false;
    }

    // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains
    // a file extension, skip.
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/index.html")
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) =>
    url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith(".png"),
  // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: "images",
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("message event");
});

// BrowserPetsWorker.js

self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  console.log("push event");

  // Our server puts everything needed to show the notification
  // in our JSON data.
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification("Welcome Assistant", {
      body: "sample body",
    })
  );
});

// BrowserPetsWorker.js

addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("service worker activated");
});
addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("service worker installed");
});

self.onactivate = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log("on activate");
};

self.oninstall = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log("on install");
};

self.onpushsubscriptionchange = (event) => {
  console.log("on push subscription change");
  console.log(event);
};

let navigate: (to: string) => void;
let dispatch: (action: any) => Promise<AnyAction>;

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("message event");
  const { type } = event.data;

  if (type === "init") {
    navigate = event.data.navigate;
    dispatch = event.data.dispatch;
  }
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  if (event.action === "accept") {
    self.clients.matchAll().then((clients) => {
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        client.postMessage({
          type: "notificationClick",
          data: { id: "112", notificationType: "Accept" }, // Add any additional data you need
        });
      });
    });
  } else if (event.action === "reject") {
    console.log("You rejected the notification!");
  } else {
    console.log("Notification clicked, but no action taken.");
  }
});

// Function to check if there are active clients
const areClientsActive = async () => {
  const clientList = await self.clients.matchAll();
  return clientList.length > 0;
};

// Example usage within an event listener
self.addEventListener("push", async (event) => {
  console.log("push event");

  // Check if there are active clients
  const clientsActive = await areClientsActive();

  if (clientsActive) {
    // Notify clients or perform actions when the app is active
    self.registration.showNotification("Welcome Assistant", {
      body: "sample body",
    });

    // Dispatch a custom event to the clients
    self.clients.matchAll().then((clients) => {
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        client.postMessage({
          type: "displayButton", // You can define your own event type
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    // Perform actions when the app is not active
    // For example, you might want to store the push notification data for later use
    console.log(
      "App is not active. Store the notification data for later use."
    );
  }
});

// Listen for messages from the clients
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  const { type } = event.data;
});

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("Service worker installed");
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("Service worker activated");
});



/// <reference lib="webworker" />
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { ExpirationPlugin } from "workbox-expiration";
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from "workbox-strategies";
import { fetchDataById } from "./redux/features/appointment/dataSlice";
import { AsyncThunkAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Dispatch, AnyAction } from "redux";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./redux/app/hook";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp("/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$");
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== "navigate") {
      return false;
    }

    // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.
    if (url.pathname.startsWith("/_")) {
      return false;
    }

    // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains
    // a file extension, skip.
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/index.html")
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) =>
    url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith(".png"),
  // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: "images",
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("message event");
});

// BrowserPetsWorker.js

self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  console.log("push event");

  // Our server puts everything needed to show the notification
  // in our JSON data.
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification("Welcome Assistant", {
      body: "sample body",
    })
  );
});

// BrowserPetsWorker.js

addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("service worker activated");
});
addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("service worker installed");
});

self.onactivate = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log("on activate");
};

self.oninstall = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log("on install");
};

self.onpushsubscriptionchange = (event) => {
  console.log("on push subscription change");
  console.log(event);
};

let navigate: (to: string) => void;
let dispatch: (action: any) => Promise<AnyAction>;

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("message event");
  const { type } = event.data;

  if (type === "init") {
    navigate = event.data.navigate;
    dispatch = event.data.dispatch;
  }
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  if (event.action === "accept") {
    self.clients.matchAll().then((clients) => {
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        client.postMessage({
          type: "notificationClick",
          data: { id: "112", notificationType: "Accept" }, // Add any additional data you need
        });
      });
    });
  } else if (event.action === "reject") {
    console.log("You rejected the notification!");
  } else {
    console.log("Notification clicked, but no action taken.");
  }
});

// Function to check if there are active clients
const areClientsActive = async () => {
  const clientList = await self.clients.matchAll();
  return clientList.length > 0;
};

// Example usage within an event listener
self.addEventListener("push", async (event) => {
  console.log("push event");

  // Check if there are active clients
  const clientsActive = await areClientsActive();

  if (clientsActive) {
    // Notify clients or perform actions when the app is active
    self.registration.showNotification("Welcome Assistant", {
      body: "sample body",
    });

    // Dispatch a custom event to the clients
    self.clients.matchAll().then((clients) => {
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        client.postMessage({
          type: "displayButton", // You can define your own event type
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    // Perform actions when the app is not active
    // For example, you might want to store the push notification data for later use
    console.log(
      "App is not active. Store the notification data for later use."
    );
  }
});

// Listen for messages from the clients
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  const { type } = event.data;
});

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("Service worker installed");
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("Service worker activated");
});
```

I need to push the notification on top of the screen when app is active until user will take action , it should be displayed

this is about my question
*your text*